# Authenticate against AzureAD (OAuth2) without registering a client?

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I'm trying to create a web api in Azure that allows a user to access it.
I don't care whether the user calls the api via postman, curl or a .net console app, as long as the user can authenticate against the AzureAD protecting the resource, he should be in.

However, all documentation I have seen so far require me to register a client with AzureAD.

So, I've got an example working, but I had to register the console app in AzureAD.

Now, there maybe hundreds or thousands of developers developing apps against my API. Obviously I don't want to have to register each single one with AzureAD. In fact, I don't even want to have to know about them.

How can I actually do that?  I care about users, not client apps.
Or is this something AzureAD B2C does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Now, there maybe hundreds or thousands of developers developing apps against my API. Obviously I don't want to have to register each single one with AzureAD. In fact, I don't even want to have to know about them.

You only need to register one app(web app) to protect the web API. And if you want the web api consumed by different organization, you need to enable the `Multi-tenanted` feature on the Azure portal.

After that, if the other developers want to consumer the web API, they also need to register the one app on their tenant and grant you web API app to their app. After that then can acquire the access token for the web API and request the web API with the access token.

More detail about the scenario about calling web API, you can refer the code sample below:

[active-directory-dotnet-webapp-webapi-openidconnect](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-webapi-openidconnect)

And if the sencario is multi-tenant, you also can refer the document below about detailed info:

[How to sign in any Azure Active Directory (AD) user using the multi-tenant application pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-devhowto-multi-tenant-overview)